# Saving 3rd party dependencies directly to Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, build, continuous-integration, dependencies

`https://pub.dev/` is blocked by a corporate firewall so `pub get` does not work unless going on the public wifi, download the packages and switch back. That being said, for building a project on a cloud system (Jenkins?), pulling these packages will be impossible, so how feasible is it to save the dependencies directly to a project so they are saved without running a `pub get` during each build?

Is there any tools that can handle managing the dependencies directly in the project, possibly saving all dependencies used in a project under a folder ( GO-lang has tools like `go vendor` for example).

I already read `http://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages` but I didn't see anything that gave any info on it.

Answer (score 0):

"pub get" isn't run during each build. You manually run it when you've changed the `pubspec.yaml` file with new packages or new versions of packages to update your hosted packages.

You can find the packages you are already using in the same location as your Flutter SDK under the ".pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org" directory.

If you need to keep them when moving your project somewhere else, you can copy that directory, and its contents ,and move it the new location of your Flutter SDK.